# How to Display table data in a specific format

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Hey there I'm looking for a specific output based on the table below

Database Table

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Department  Division      Name   Level1    Level2  Level3 GrandTotal ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Insurance   Distribution  John                1               3      ║
║ Insurance   Distribution  Mark     1                          3      ║
║ Insurance   Distribution  Joe      1                          3      ║
║ Marketing   Distribution  Rob                         1       2      ║
║ Marketing   Distribution  Sam      1                          2      ║
║ Claims      Solutions     Bob      1                          3      ║
║ Claims      Solutions     Tom      1                          3      ║
║ Claims      Solutions     Gin                         1       3      ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

The output i'm looking for is

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║     Department  Division     Name     Level1  Level2     Level3  GrandTotal ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║     Insurance   Distributon                                           3     ║
║                              John               1                     1     ║
║                              Mark        1                            1     ║
║                              Joe         1                            1     ║
║     Marketing  Distribution                                           2     ║
║                              Rob                            1         1     ║
║                              Sam         1                            1     ║
║     Claims     Solution                                               3     ║
║                              Bob         1                            1     ║
║                              Tom         1                            1     ║
║                              Gin                            1         1     ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

First if there was a name for this type of table output I would apologizes since I don't know it and would have made the title better. I had an idea of using a cursors to go through each line and store the department and division in a variable and checking each time it was the same and if so blank out the department and division until they changed. But I'm hoping there is an easier way to do this. Any Help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Just quick ... you can do this with `ROLLUP`. I have no time right now to write a comprehensive answer, but perhaps you can look it up or somebody else will write an answer.

Comment: You can also do it with UNION ALL and an artificial ORDER BY column that doesn't appear in the SELECT list.

Comment: Thanks SQLPolice and Tab Alleman for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @SQLPolice said, you could do something like this with rollup, but I can't really recommend it. It gets messy and difficult to maintain. This should really be done outside the database:

```
select 
  case when grouping(name) = 1 then department end as department, 
  case when grouping(name) = 1 then division end as division, 
  name,
  case when grouping(name) = 0 then sum(isnull(level1,0)) end as level1,
  case when grouping(name) = 0 then sum(isnull(level2,0)) end as level2,
  case when grouping(name) = 0 then sum(isnull(level3,0)) end as level3,
  case when grouping(name) = 1 then sum(isnull(level1,0)) + sum(isnull(level2,0)) + sum(isnull(level3,0)) end as GrandTotal
from 
  table1
group by
  department, 
  division, 
  rollup(name)
order by
  table1.department,
  table1.division,
  grouping(name) desc
```

My assumption was that grand total should actually be the grand total of the rows, and shown only on the summary level, not for all, and doesn't really exist in the data.

The trick here is grouping(field) that tells if the row is the detail row or the summary row, and rollup creates the summaries on higher level.

Here's [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c0160/10) to play around.

Comment: Thanks JamesZ for the response and the post I will give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: JamesZ quick question in the case of the test table there were only 3 level but what if there are more than 15 or a unknown number of levels, how would you change the above since a case would be pretty long. If there was a way. thanks

Comment: @JayJay Having unknown number of columns in the select is always nasty thing to have and you'll end up creating dynamic SQL, which is even less fun to maintain (or even understand after 6 months). You should really try to do things like this outside the database.

Comment: JamesZ thanks again it worked exactly the way i needed it. Also thanks to everyone else that give suggestions.